# Centralize php globals?

Tags: php, scope, global-variables

I have a functions.php file that, among other functions, includes the following:

```
function head() {
    global $brand, $brandName, $logo, $slogan, $siteName, $title, $titles, $keyword, $keywords, $description, $descriptions, $bodyclass, $bodyClass, $page;
    include('_assets/inc/head.php');
}

function foot() {
    global $brand, $brandName, $logo, $slogan, $siteName, $title, $titles, $keyword, $keywords, $description, $descriptions, $bodyclass, $bodyClass, $page;
    include('_assets/inc/foot.php');
}
```

I needed to duplicate the globals line into the `foot()` to get variables I was calling in the  foot.php to display.  Isn't there a place for me to centralize these globals so I only need to place the global line once in my site?

---

As per Jack's directions, I now have:

```
class Page {
    private $context;
    public function __construct(array $context) {
        $this->context = $context;
    }
    public function printHead() {
        extract($this->context);
        include '_assets/inc/head.php';
    }
    public function printFoot() {
        extract($this->context);
        include '_assets/inc/foot.php';
    }
}
$page = new Page(array(
    'brand' => 'myBrand',
    'brandName' => '<span class="brand">'.$brand.' <sup><span aria-hidden="true" class="icon_search"></span></sup></span>',
    'logo' => '<a href="/" class="brand">'.$brandName.'</a>',
    'slogan' => '<span class="slogan">Find A Real Estate Professional</span>',
    'siteName' => $logo.' | Directory of Real Estate Professionals',
    'title' => 'Directory of Real Estate Professionals | '.$brand.'',
    'titles' => array (
        'home' => 'Find A Real Estate Professional | '.$brand.''
    );
        if(isset($titles[$page])){
            $title = $titles[$page];
        }
    'keyword' => ''.$brand.', real estate professionals, real estate directory, real estate agents, realtor directory, real estate brokers, real estate lawyers, real estate insurance agents, real estate appraisers, real estate staging consultants',
    'keywords' => array (
        '' => ''
    );
        if(isset($keywords[$page])){
            $keyword = $keywords[$page];
        }
    'description' => ''.$brand.' is a complete directory of real estate professionals, including agents, brokers, appraisers, insurance agents, stagers, lawyers, and more.',
    'descriptions' => array (
        '' => ''
    );
        if(isset($descriptions[$page])){
            $description = $descriptions[$page];
        }
    'bodyclass' => ' page bbfix',
    'bodyClass' => array (
        'home' => 'home'
    ); 
        if(isset($bodyClass[$page])){
            $bodyclass = $bodyClass[$page];
        }
    'page' => $page
));
$page->printHead();
$page->printFoot();
```

However, my code has errors relating to the arrays. :(

Comment: There's always `$GLOBALS`, but I think you could benefit from some better object-oriented code design.

Comment: this is some scary code :)

Comment: I'm semi certain that globals were intentionally made a bit cumbersome to use, just to keep people from using them indiscriminately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please don't jump to constructs like [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) and the equally bad [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php); having global state is [not recommended](https://sheriframadan.com/2011/07/why-is-the-global-state-bad/).

That said, with some small changes you can improve on your design by using objects to encapsulate your state:

```
class Page
{
    private $context;

    public function __construct(array $context)
    {
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    public function printHead()
    {
        extract($this->context);
        include '_assets/inc/head.php';
    }

    // same for foot()
}
```

To use it:

```
$page = new Page(array(
    'brand' => 'foo',
    'brandName' => 'bar',
    // etc
));

$page->printHead();
```

The `Page` class encapsulates the context upon construction; this state is extracted just before your assets are included into the script. To the included scripts it would be as if the variables were global all along.

Comment: I guess `public function head()` should do binding (via `ob_*` )not sending an output. Because sending content is kind of another responsibility. And then it should be echo'ed like `echo $page->head();`

Comment: @DaveJust Sure, you could look at it like that; alternatively, just a rename of the method to `printHead()` could overcome it as well :)

Comment: Okay, @Jack, I attempted what you advised and edited my code, but when it came to the arrays for my variables, I have line errors.  I've updated my question with my new code, as per your example.

Comment: Jack, the errors I'm getting are specific to the array lines I added.    The first error is `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mydomain/_assets/functions.php on line 42` which pertains to the `};` in the middle of `'titles' => array (
      'home' => 'Find A Real Estate Professional | '.$brand.''
  );
   if(isset($titles[$page])){
    $title = $titles[$page];
   }`

Comment: @theFreelancer Fixing parse errors is beyond the scope of this answer, I'm assuming you have the basic skills of making a script work.

Comment: Jack, my bad.  I'll do some research, and see what I can find.  If all else fails I'll open a new question.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a centralized reference to all global variables in PHP. It's called [the `$GLOBALS` array](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php).

> An associative array containing references to all variables which are currently defined in the global scope of the script. The variable names are the keys of the array.

For example:

```
$GLOBALS['brand'];
$GLOBALS['logo'];
 // And so on
```